# proper way to swap unions?

Tags: c++, swap, unions

I have a class which has a union as one of its members. I also am a big fan of the [copy/swap idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Copy-and-swap). It occurred to me that there doesn't appear to be any correct (in the sense of the standard) to swap unions!

Here's the best that I could come up with:

```
char tmp[sizeof(U)];
memcpy(tmp, &u1, sizeof(U));
memcpy(&u1, &u2, sizeof(U));
memcpy(&u2, tmp, sizeof(U));
```

Since unions (at least in c++03) require that all members be POD, I don't see why this wouldn't work. But it just doesn't **feel** right. Is there a more correct way to swap unions? It seems almost like something that was overlooked.

What do you guys think?

**EDIT:**

OK, I feel kinda dumb after seeing the solutions given :-). I wrote off traditional solutions like `std::swap` and assignment because when I first wrote the code, the union was an anonymous union. In the current version of the code, the union is no longer anonymous and traditional solutions seem to work just fine. Thanks.

Comment: I think unions should be avoided in general! haha

Comment: @DShook: while that is generally the case, there are some cases where they make sense.

Comment: If it's C++ only, maybe you want to implement a copy constructor on your struct, this way, you don't have to rely on a tmp array

Comment: What is wrong with `std::swap(u1, u2);` ?

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466486/c-union-assignment-is-there-a-good-way-to-do-this

Comment: @Rob Adams: I think i wrote that off because some compilers (Visual Studio I think) didn't like that.

Comment: This will break in C++11, as unions are no longer required to contain *only* POD types. So beware of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply:

```
#include <algorithm>
std::swap(u1, u2);
```

Unions are both copy-constructible and assignable, so there is no problem.

Comment: I originally had that, but I think vc++2008 barfed on it. I'll look into it again.

Comment: Come to think about it, previously the union was anonymous (it no longer is), perhaps vc++ just didn't like swapping anonymous unions?

Comment: @Evan Teran: §14.3.1 [temp.arg.type]/2 *A local type, a type with no linkage, an **unnamed type** or a type compounded from any of these types **shall not be** used as **a template-argument** for a template type-parameter.* So basically yes, you cannot use an *unnamed* union as a type argument to a template, and `std::swap` is a template.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use classical swap solution?

```
U u1, u2;
// ...
U t = u1;
u1 = u2;
u2 = t;
```

This is expected to work since assignment of unions is valid.

Comment: One should just use `std::swap`, though.

Comment: @GMan The above will work in pure C as well (probably moving temporary definition to the up), while std::swap is only for C++

Comment: And we care about C in a C++ question because...?